# p:commandButton onfocus not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In my project there are 8 text boxes and a command button. When I press the command button `onfocus` attribute is not working. So I tried to use `p:focus` which either did not work as expected.

```
<p:commandButton value="Test1" action="#{test.testAction1}" update="mainPanel">
    <p:focus for="textField"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

Do I need `p:commandButton`'s attribute `onfocus` to focus a specific component?

Answer (score 2):

**How to get focused**

First of all two different subjects must be distinguished here:

1. The `onfocus` attribute provided by several components is used to react on a focus event (occuring when the given component recieves focus). On focus the provided JavaScript is called client-side.
2. The PrimeFaces element `p:focus` is used to control focus. There is an automatic / implicit (a) and an explicit mode (b):

   a. `<p:focus />` sets the focus to the first input element. This is also validation-aware in such a way that it puts the focus on the first invalid field.

   b. `<p:focus for="..." />` causes the component with the given id to recieve focus.

   To make focus control work:

   - do not put `p:focus` inside the component element, just put it e.g. before the first one,
   - for AJAX requests, `update` the `p:focus` element as well.

Here comes a small example to fiddle around with:

```
<h:form>
    <p:focus for="textField-#{exampleForm.focusedIndex}"/>
    <p:inputText id="textField-1" /><br />
    <p:inputText id="textField-2" /><br />
    <p:inputText id="textField-3" /><br />
    <p:inputText id="textField-4" /><br />
    <p:inputText id="textField-5" onfocus="alert('last field focused.');" /><br />
    <p:commandButton value="Up" update="@form" action="#{exampleForm.decrementFocus()}" />
    <p:commandButton value="Down" update="@form" action="#{exampleForm.incrementFocus()}" />
</h:form>
```

The corresponding bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class ExampleForm implements Serializable {

    private static final int MIN_INDEX = 1;
    private static final int MAX_INDEX = 5;

    private int focusedIndex = 1;

    public int getFocusedIndex() {
        return focusedIndex;
    }

    public void setFocusedIndex(final int focusedIndex) {
        this.focusedIndex = focusedIndex;
    }

    public void incrementFocus() {
        if (focusedIndex < MAX_INDEX)
            focusedIndex++;
    }

    public void decrementFocus() {
        if (focusedIndex > MIN_INDEX)
            focusedIndex--;
    }
}
```

See also:

- PrimeFaces Show Case for [Focus](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/focus.xhtml),
- PrimeFaces [User Guide](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation).

Comment: When I use onfocus="specifyId" it will show undefined error in  browser

Comment: Yes, because the `onfocus` attribute expects JavaScript.

Comment: @Karthik: Any progress?